# OpenShift3 Online CPU Resource Limits

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I'm fairly new to the OpenShift3 Online platform.

So far I can deploy my app and set memory limits fairly easily by editing the deployment configuration.

Is there a way to assign a specific maximum number of milicores to a deployment configuration in OpenShift3 Online?

Comment: No. OpenShift Online runs in a mode where CPU request/limit are calculated in proportion to memory request/limit. 1GB of memory equates to 1 core.

Comment: In the starter package, you get 2 cores and 1 GB of memory. I'm running two pods with memory limits >=512 each. I still hit the quota on CPU?

Comment: Check out the note in our Online docs: https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#dev-cpu-requests

Comment: Okay, 512MB may be one core, I was quoting it from memory and been a long time since looked at it. Either way, it doesn't really make sense with Online Starter to say you have hit CPU quota as you have no control over it. Am wondering whether you are getting confused by messages from Starter which could be output about CPU when real issue is being out of memory, since CPU is in proportion to memory anyway.

Comment: One source of problems in Starter is using Rolling deployment strategy. If you max out memory usage, a new deployment will fail with quota issues (for both CPU and memory) as a new pod can't first be created before stopping old. You need to switch to Recreate deployment strategy. http://cookbook.openshift.org/application-lifecycle-management/how-can-i-change-the-deployment-strategy-being-used.html

Comment: Thank you for responses, everybody.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, You are correct about the rolling strategy, I no longer use it for my tests, I started using the recreate one the moment I added a second pod.
I believe if you have two pods with the Starter package, you can't really use the rolling strategy.
I get notifications about hitting the max CPU, right now I'm just teaching my self the platform, and I'm thinking big, How would OpenShift3 Online handle this situation? Will it kill my pods? just throttle them? can I configure a strategy in OS3 Online?
These are my concerns right now.